# Understanding "exterior" of a space embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to understand what the "exterior" of a space embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exterior is the complement, within $R^3$.

(For general subspaces $A$ of a topological space $B$, the exterior of $A$ in the topological space $B$ is the complement of the closure of $A$ in $B$, thus providing the third part in the disjoint partition of $B$ into the interior, the boundary, and the exterior of $A$ in $B$.)